# Redirect shows the sign in page partially before redirecting in next js react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, use-effect

I have a simple app where if a user is signed in and if the user manually tries to go to /signin page he is redirected to the index page. I'm using nextjs and to achieve this is I run a function in useEffect where boolean is checked true if so I use Router.push is used to redirect the user to the index page. The functionality works fine I see a few milliseconds of sign-in page before redirecting to the index page. Why is that? is it because the useEffect is called every time after the component is rendered? basically I want to run that code before rendering component and useEffect runs after the component is rendered. I want basically to run the code something like componentWillMount. How do I do it in the functional component? or is there any other solution?

```
const SigninComponent = () => {

  



useEffect(() => {
  
  isAuth() && Router.push(`/`);
}, []);

return(
   // components 
);
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use Class based instead of functional in this case, because u need the componentWillMount lifecycle and it's more readable. If u insist on using functional component, consider put `if (isAuth()) { Router.push('/') }` before return the component and remove the useEffect. The useEffect with second parameter empty array, only run once after thee component has mounted.

Comment: @Kaslie `componentWillMount` is deprecated you should avoid to use  it.

Comment: Oooh, My bad. Then using it in Constructor should works ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thats because `useEffect` will only run after component has mounted.
You can use different solutions :

1. **Conditional rendering**, add a loading field to state that is true by default, when it is true your component will render something like a spinner/loading component, if `isAuth()` return false then you will render something else (most likely a login form).
   **Pseudocode**:

```
const SigninComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isAuth()){
      Router.push(`/`);
    }else{
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }, []);

  if(!loading){
    return <Login />
  }else{
    return <MyloaderComponent />
  }
}
```

2. **Use HOC component**, similar to above but  you will wrap the above logic in a HOC component
3. **Use `getServerSideProps`** and run `isAuth()` server-side instead that client-side, if you redirect inside `getServerSideProps` the component will not render at all. (you can use `getServerSideProps` only in pages)

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const auth = await isAuth() // or other any logic, like read cookies...

  if (!auth) {
      const { res } = ctx;
      res.setHeader("location", "/");
      res.statusCode = 302;
      res.end();
      return;
  }

  return {
      props: {}, // or return user
  };
};
```

Comment: Even `isAuth` need time to complete, it will block all the process before render. But that's not the reason why the app render the component first instead of redirect. The reason why the app render the component, because the `useEffect` it will only run after component has mounted or rendered. But yeah, you provide the right solution :)

Comment: How do you protect the user from accessing the login page after authentication? Suppose I have two dynamic routes /[user] and /[user]/dashboard. If I use Router.push(/[user]/dashboard) to protect the login page after authentication, then I have a different problem. If I go to /[user] and hit refresh, it will redirect me to /[user]/dashboard. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score -1):

You may consider using Redirect Component

```js
const SigninComponent = () => {
  if (isAuth()) return <Redirect to="/" />
  
  return(
     // components 
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You dont need Redirect with next.js , since you have Router. And you still have a page flash with this solution.